# Send JavaScript arrays to a php page and convert them to PHP format

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to pass the array created in Javascript "operacionesInicial" from the page "NuevaFichaAluminio.php" to another called "SalvarFichaAluminio.php"
For this I have this piece of code:

```
function salvar(formu)
{
  
    if(confirm("Se procede al salvado de la ficha. ¿Está seguro?")) {
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo ($ruta_raiz) ?>/aludec/SalvadoFichas/SalvarFichaAluminio.php",
       data: { operacionesInicial : operacionesInicial},
       success: function() {
              alert("Success");
        }
});
formu.action = "<?php echo ($ruta_raiz) ?>/aludec/SalvadoFichas/SalvarFichaAluminio.php";
formu.submit();
    }
}
```

In "SalvarFichaAluminio.php" I have this other:

```
$operacionesInicial = $_POST["operacionesInicial"];
$operacionesInicial = explode(',', $operacionesInicial);
```

But it does not show me the content that I pass to it.
What am I doing wrong?

On the other hand, can the array be collected directly on the same PHP page without having to create the SalvarFichaAluminio.php. I really wouldn't need it, but I just don't see how to do it directly.
Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to perform an AJAX call, but at the end you call `submit()` on the form. That doesn't make sense because then you're making a new request (regular form submission), interrupting your AJAX.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Eliminating formu.submit(); it do correctly. Thanks!!